# Типизация сложного JSON файла (Typescript)

Tags: json, typescript, redux

На стадии осваивания Typescript и Redux столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Имеем сложный JSON файл с такой сруктурой:

```
{
    "person" : 
    [
        {
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "patronymic": "",
            "age" : "",
            "city" : ""           
        }
    ],

    "contacts" : 
    [
        {   "photo": "./photo.jpg",            
            "tel" : "",
            "mail" : "mailto:",
        }

    ],


    "hobby" : ["Книги", "Музыка", "Фильмы"],

    "experience" : 
    [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "year" : "",
            "organization" : "",
            "position" : "",
            "description" : ""
        } 
    ],

    "education" :
    [
        {
            "year" : "",
            "institution" : "",
            "department" : "",
            "specialization" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Через Redux получаю эти данные:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";


interface Idatatype {
  data: [];
  loading: boolean;
}

const DataList: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { data, loading } = useSelector((state: Idatatype) => state);  

  return (
    <>
      {loading &&
        data.map((item: any) => {
          return <li>{item}</li>;
        })}
  
  );
};
export default DataList;
```

Подскажите, как типизировать полученные данные и вывести их

Comment: А в чём собственно сложность?

Comment: как размапить например data.person ?

Comment: Что значит - размапить? Вам надо описать стрктуру дл якаждой сущности

Comment: типизируйте в лоб, делов-то. https://pastebin.com/eBwRsSfM только структура данных у вас хаотична, персоны, хобби, образование - всё порознь и не связано

Comment: можно визульную подсказку?

Answer (score 0):

Я создал тип для JSON

```
declare module datatype {
  export interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    patronymic: string;
    age: string;
    city: string;
  }

  export interface Contact {
    photo: string;
    tel: string;
    mail: string;
    telegram: string;
    github: string;
    linkedin: string;
  }

  export interface Position {
    position: string;
    employment: string;
    schedule: string;
    about: string;
  }

  export interface Experience {
    id: number;
    year: string;
    organization: string;
    position: string;
    description: string;
  }

  export interface Education {
    year: string;
    institution: string;
    department: string;
    specialization: string;
  }

  export interface RootObject {
    person: Person[];
    contacts: Contact[];
    position: Position[];
    hobby: string[];
    languages: string[];
    hardskils: string[];
    experience: Experience[];
    education: Education[];
    CV: [];
    loading: boolean;
  }
}

export { cvtype };
```

в коде исправил, но не уверен что верно

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { datatype } from "../../types/data";


const DataList: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { data, loading }: { data: datatype.RootObject[]; loading: boolean } =
    useSelector((state: datatype.RootObject) => state);



  return (
    <>
      {loading &&
        data.map((item: any, index: number) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })}
    </>
)
}
```